# JSON Jackson maps to other constructor from what I was expecting

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this JSON:

```
{ 
   "label":{    
            "label":"1D812", 
            "version":"01"
           },    
   "productionDate":"140415", 
   "boxNumber":"003",
   "quantity":11000, 
   "order":"0000", 
   "documentId":"DOC-HHS",
   "location":1
}
```

and I run these commands to create a `Box` object

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Box box = mapper.readValue(myJSON, Box.class);
```

In `Box` class there is the following constructor:

```
public Box(Label label, String productionDate, String boxNumber, int quantity, String order,  String documentId,int location ) {
   this.label = label;
   this.quantity = quantity;
   this.order = order;
   this.boxNumber = boxNumber;
   this.location = location;
   this.documentId = documentId;
   this.productionDate = productionDate;
}
```

And in `Label` class I have these constructors (in that order, if it matters)

```
public Label() {
}    

public Label(String label) {
        this.label = label;
}

public Label(String label, String version) {
    this.label = label;
    this.version = version;
}

public Label(String label, String version, SupplierL supplier) {
    this.label = label;
    this.version = version;
    this.supplier = supplier;
    this.labelWithVersion = label + "-" + version;
}
```

When I `System.out.println(box.toString());` I see that:

```
Box{label=Label{label=1D812, version=01, supplier=null}, etc...}
```

I am wondering, why it used the `Label` constructor with the 3 arguments and not that with the 2?

Comment: I just realized that `System.out.println(box.toString()); ` prints what `toString()` arguments has. Where in my case  it has `@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Label{" + "label=" + label + ", version=" + version + ", supplier=" + supplier + '}';
    }`.. I got stuck for a moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it calls that 3-arg constructor at all. How would it know what's what? Instead it calls the no-args constructor and set the field values.

If you want it to call a particular constructor, use the `@JsonCreator` annotation. Note that you can only set it on one.

See this answer for details:

[How to deserialize a class with overloaded constructors using JsonCreator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931082/how-to-deserialize-a-class-with-overloaded-constructors-using-jsoncreator)

Comment: you are right. I got stuck for a moment
`System.out.println` prints what `tostring()` has as arguments

Answer (score 0):

There's no Supplier in your JSON object. So it correcly used 2 argument constructor:

```
"label":{    
        "label":"1D812", 
        "version":"01"
        }
```

And that's exactly what you see in the output:

```
label=Label{label=1D812, version=01, supplier=null}
```