# Multiple JsonCreator annotated methods

Tags: java, jackson

### Initial Question

Is it possible to have multiple `@JsonCreator` methods, and for jackson to detect which one it should use depending on the method definiton?

```
@JsonCreator
public static StateOfComm factory(String id) {
    return StateOfComm.valueOf(id);
}

@JsonCreator
public static StateOfComm factory(CustomType value) {
    return StateOfComm.valueOf(value.getId());  
}
```

### Update

The JSON that fails (because id=null), is the following:

```
{"comment":null, "processes":[{"stateOfComm":{"id":"CA"}}]}
```

The following works:

```
 {"comment":null, "processes":[{"stateOfComm":"CA"}]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this problem by getting rid of the `@JsonCreator` annotations, and using a custom `StdDeserializer` that did the trick.

Here is an example:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(
        ignoreUnknown = true
    )
    @JsonDeserialize(
        using = IdTextEntry.Deserializer.class
    )
    @Data
    public class IdTextEntry implements IdAndText {
        String id;
        String text;

        public IdTextEntry(Enum<?> val) {
            if (val != null) {
                this.id = val.name();
                this.text = val.toString();
            }

        }        

        public static class Deserializer extends StdDeserializer<IdTextEntry> {
            public Deserializer() {
                this((Class)null);
            }

            Deserializer(Class<?> vc) {
                super(vc);
            }

            public IdTextEntry deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
                JsonNode node = (JsonNode)jp.getCodec().readTree(jp);
                String id;
                if (node.has("id") && node.has("text")) {
                    id = node.get("id").asText();
                    String text = node.get("text").asText();
                    return new IdTextEntry(id, text);
                } else if (node.has("id")) {
                    id = node.get("id").asText();
                    return new IdTextEntry(id, id);
                } else {
                    id = node.asText();
                    return new IdTextEntry(id, id);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to parse both JSON examples in your question by:

1. using `jackson-modules-java8` version 2.9.1 dependency
2. invoking the java 8 compiler with `-parameters` argument
3. introducing all argument constructors for all classes involved
4. avoiding `@JsonProperty` on static creation methods and constructors
5. defining a class:

   ```
   class CustomType {
       private final String id;
   }
   ```

My understanding is that Jackson couldn't discern between multiple creators in older version. E.g. see answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15931483/1413133) and github issue [here](https://github.com/fasterxml/jackson-databind/issues/421). It seems that the option to have parameter names in compiled code in java 8 helps in this case.

Answer (score -1):

You can have multiple @JsonCreator methods but it requires to use @JsonProperty for specifying which property you are initializing.

```
@JsonCreator
public static StateOfComm factory(@JsonProperty("id") String id) {
    return StateOfComm.valueOf(id);
}

@JsonCreator
public static StateOfComm factory(@JsonProperty("value") CustomType value) {
    return StateOfComm.valueOf(value.getId());  
}
```

Comment: I did a test and it doesn't work 100%. Adding an example of the JSON. I think @JsonProperty is to specify the order of the properties but does not help to select the specific factory `@JsonCreator` method.

Comment: @MenelaosBakopoulos Same for me, it was completely ignored. Finally I ended up with only one JsonCreator and checking the value type inside of the method.